IndexError in simple loop
I've written a very simple piece of code:
a=[]
for i in range(1,5):
  b = i**3
  a.append(b)
for i in range(1,5):
  print(a[i])

when I run this, I get the output 8 27 64 and the error message IndexError: list index is out of range.
Basically, a[5] is showing up as an error since it hasn't been defined in the previous loop, which terminated at i=4
My question is, given that the second loop is also exiting at i=4, why is a(5) being checked for at all?
Also, I'm getting no error message for i=1. Is this because NULL has been assigned to a(1)?
Thanks

please fix the formatting so that the code is readable.

Lists begin at 0,
that's why a[4] causes the error.
This will work
a=[]
for i in range(1,5):
    b = i**3
    a.append(b)
for i in range(1,5):
    print(a[i-1])

and it would make sense loop over the list to display the result
for item in a: 
    print(item)


The reason you get the error is that the second loop starts from i = 1 to u i = 4 but you should go from 0 to 3. This can be fixed by changing the range of the second loop.
a=[]
for i in range(1,5):
  b = i**3
  a.append(b)
for i in range(4):
  print(a[i])

